# Nifi regex on attributes

Tags: apache-nifi

I have flowfiles with filename like that:
`xxx2019xxx.txt`

Where `xxx` are letters, I want to extract the year (`2019` or whatever looks like a 4 digits numbers) within the filename. It seems to me that the Expression Language´s regex functions like `matches(...)` just return a boolean value. Any ideas how to extract the year?

Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a dynamic property (click the **+** icon on the top right of the "Properties" tab of the `UpdateAttribute` processor). Name it "extractedYear" or whatever you like. The value of this property should be an [Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) statement like:

```
${filename:replace('.*(\d{4}).*', '$1')}
```

That says to *replace* (in the new attribute, not modifying the existing `filename` attribute) the matched pattern (anything + 4 digits + anything) with the *first capture group* (aka the 4 digits).

Comment: Thank you Andy for your quick and helpfull answer. I managed to did it with slight modification to your EL:

    ${filename:replaceAll('.*(\d{4}).*', '$1')}

Comment: I would only add, that `replace(...)` does not take Regex as a parameter (as of version 1.14.0) but `replaceAll(...)` does...